# Struct pointer versus actual struct

Tags: c, pointers

Why is struct `somestruct* mystruct = ...` a pointer to a struct of type `somestruct`? Doesn't the `*` dereference mystruct?

Answer (score 5):

**No.** In a variable declaration, the `*` is part of the type specifier.

I know that's a little confusing at first, but that's really just how it is. If you find it hard to get used to try copying down a number of expressions involving pointer notation and practice translating them into English, like "somestruct pointer my struct equals..." and "the value pointed to by mystruct is...".

Comment: Further info: many symbols have different meaning in a declaration than in a statement, e.g. `*` `&` `=`

Answer (score 1):

`struct somestruct* mystruct;` makes `mystruct` a variable of TYPE: `struct somestruct*`.

Hence `mystruct` is a pointer to `struct somestruct`

This is during declaration of `mystruct`.

While using `mystruct` : `(*mystruct).foo=10;` dereferences `mystruct`.

Answer (score 0):

The * operator is a deferencing operator when used for referring to already declared variables and indicates that the initialized variable is a pointer when used for initialization

Comment: In the declaration it is not an operator at all. "Operator" means that it takes input value(s) and yields an output value.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding this requires you to understand basics of pointers, and how pointers work. In summary, each variable you declared in a program is stored in a location in the computer's memory, and when accessing the variables, the hardware uses the addresses of that location.

Hence, a pointer is just a variable that stores the memory address of another variable.

```
somestruct *mystruct = ...
```

tells the computer that 
"Hey, this is a pointer of type somestruct name mystruct!". The ' * ' infront of mystruct just tells the compiler that this is a pointer.

This is the standard way of how we define a pointer, and if you can understand the followings, the same concept applies to declaring a struct pointer:

```
char *mychar = ...
double *mydouble = ...
```

Get it? the first line simply tells C compiler that this is a pointer to type char name *mychar. Have a guess of what the 2nd line does. :)