# Unable to understand "typedef" and pointer usage in structs (C)

Tags: pointers, data-structures, struct, linked-list, typedef

My questions have to do with very early stages of learning lists in C.I haven't been able to find a clear answer to my questions anywhere whether it has to to with the simplest code there is.(*I'm going to give you an example of what i don't clearly understand on a very simple code just for you to get where i lose my understanding.It's the same question i have with more complicated ones.*)

```c
   struct node{
       int data;
       struct node *next;
   };
```

i get what data and next are used for as variables but i don't get: what **struct node *next really means**.Do we create a new stuct named next that has new data and next members?What i also don't get is the * usage in next.

**Below follows a code that aims to create tabs and add site addresses to these tabs.Kind of what a borwser would do.InfoSession in an informational code.The list i'm creating is a double linked list.**But i don't understand two things:
1)What does really TabNodePtr LastTab mean for example?Is LastTab a new struct now that has all the above :

```c
TabNodePtr PrevTab, NextTab;
SiteNodePtr FirstSite;
SiteNodePtr CurrSite;
```

as members?Same with the SiteNodePtr s. I don't get how they are all linked together it's all a ball of christmas garlands to me right now.
2)Why do we use pointers for the members?And don't just go with TabNode LastTab for instance?Where do pointers make a diffrence and we must add them?

```c
   typedef struct TabNode *TabNodePtr;
    typedef struct SiteNode *SiteNodePtr;

    struct InfoSession {
        TabNodePtr FirstTab;
        TabNodePtr LastTab;
        TabNodePtr CurrTab;
    };

    struct TabNode {    
        TabNodePtr PrevTab, NextTab;
        SiteNodePtr FirstSite;
        SiteNodePtr CurrSite;
    };

    struct SiteNode{
        SiteNodePtr PrevSite, NextSite;
        TabNodePtr UpTab;
    };
```

Comment: It seems you could really need to read a couple of beginner books, as they should tell you all you seem to wonder about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Struct pointer versus actual struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800447/struct-pointer-versus-actual-struct)

Answer (score 1):

*You have a long, long way to go....*

Let me try, if I can help you a little in your journey of learning C language.

> what `struct node *next` really means.Do we create a new stuct named `next` that has new data and `next` members?What i also don't get is the `*` usage in `next`.

```
struct node *next;
```

This statement declares a variable named `next` which is of type `struct node *` which means `next` is a pointer which can point to address of type `struct node`.
For e.g. in the statement `int *p;`, variable `p` is of type `int *` which means `p` is a pointer which can point to `int`. *[For pointers, check [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer) or [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17898/whats-a-nice-explanation-for-pointers) or google it or refer any good book]*.

Have you ever heard of **self-referential structure** in C?
**A self-referential structure is a structure in which one of its members is a pointer to the structure itself.**

So, in this structure declaration:

```
       -------------------------------------------------
       |                                               |
       v                                               |
  struct node{                                     -----------
      int data;                                    |         |
      struct node *next;   // next is a pointer to struct node, i.e. pointer to self
  };
```

the `struct node` is a self referential structure. *[For more details on self-referential structure check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39151133/what-is-self-referencing-structure-in-c) and for its usage check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48509981/why-do-we-use-pointers-in-self-referential-structs)].*

> But i don't understand two things: 1)What does really `TabNodePtr LastTab` mean for example?Is `LastTab` a new struct now that has all the above....

First of all, read thoroughly about pointers (more specifically pointer to a structure) in C.

`typedef` is used to create an **alias name** for other data type. *[Read more about typedef [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) and about typedef a struct [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions?rq=1) or refer any good book.]*

So, when you write

```
typedef struct TabNode *TabNodePtr;
```

that means, now, the `TabNodePtr` is an alias of `struct TabNode *` type and you can use `TabNodePtr` to declare variable of type `struct TabNode *`.

So, after the above `typedef....` statement, when you write

```
TabNodePtr xyz;
```

is exactly same as this

```
struct TabNode *xyz;
```

In your code:

```
TabNodePtr LastTab;
```

this declares the variable `LastTab` of type `struct TabNode *` which means `LastTab` is a pointer to `struct TabNode`.

So, this is

```
    struct InfoSession {
        TabNodePtr FirstTab;
        TabNodePtr LastTab;
        TabNodePtr CurrTab;
    };
```

is exactly same as this

```
    struct InfoSession {
        struct TabNode *FirstTab;
        struct TabNode *LastTab;
        struct TabNode *CurrTab;
    };
```

Same is for `SiteNodePtr` as well which is an alias of `struct SiteNode *`.

> 2)Why do we use pointers for the members?And don't just go with `TabNode LastTab` for instance?Where do pointers make a diffrence and we must add them?

*`Why do we use pointers for the members?`* or *`Why do we use pointers?`* - This is a very natural question for someone who does not know or know very little about pointers in C and for most of the beginners it is a topic which confuses them a lot. But believe me once you gain proper knowledge about pointers and learn to use them, you will never go back. Pointers are an irresistibly very powerful programming construct. To understand - *`Why do we use pointers....`*, first you have gain knowledge about pointers. For starters, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome).

Happy learning.... enjoy..